# Code: KS179; The name 'kind' is not a recognized parameter for this operator when used with make-series

Tags: kql

I am using make-series operator with kind=nonempty flag, as suggested in kql documentation :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/make-seriesoperator

However I get this warning :'kind' is not a recognized parameter for this operator'
Why is that ?

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in the intellisense, please ignore this, it will be fixed soon.